# #Define's scope throughout library?

Tags: c, scope, c-preprocessor

Say I have a constant:

```
#define PI 3.14
```

Say I have a static library with multiple header and source files. If I declare this in the header file, will its scope apply to all of the source files? Or do the source files need to include the header with the declaration of `PI`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will need to include the file which contains #define PI 3.14, otherwise the preprocessor will not read the #define line, and subsequently the compile will fail.

In C++, a good way to think of the compile process is that each individual C++ file is first run through a preprocessor, which takes all the #define, #include, and other preprocessor statements and replaces them throughout the code, then compiled (at this point, the C++ file and anything brought in via #include treated almost as if they were one very large single file), then after that, a linker takes the final output of the preprocess/compile stage for all of the C++ files and assembles them into one final output file.  The preprocessor (Which handles the defines) works before the compile stage, not during linkage.

Comment: It's probably clearer to say that there are three stages: preprocessing, compiling, and linking, and that the `#define` and `#include` are preprocessor directives, so they take place before compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The definition has to be included in each module.

Technically, it has no "scope".  It is only a text replacement operation that happens prior to compilation.  You could also look into your compiler settings for a way to specify pre-processor definitions.  This is often a project setting available easily through your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

They will need to include the define, however if you need a define across all files you can do a compiler level switch.